# Angular 5 set value of non angular attribute

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I want to set the value of an attribute that is not connected to any component or directive:

```
<section *ngFor="let view of views; let last = last" [ngSwitch]="view.type" data-menu-title="{{view.title}}">
```

The attribute in question is: `data-menu-title`

However, when I do this I get the following error:

```
Can't bind to 'menu-title' since it isn't a known property of 'section'. ("lass="slides">
```

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: So what is `data-menu-title`?

Comment: try with `[attr.data-menu-title]="view.title"` - https://angular.io/guide/cheatsheet

Comment: @Und3rTow that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [attr.x]="expression" method? Like this:

```
[attr["data-menu-title"]]="view.title"
```